# How to handle an ajax response which is asynchronous

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, asynchronous

I want to retrieve some data from my database in nodejs.
Retrieving those data is an async request, as we well as the ajax request.

Client.js

```
$.ajax('localhost/Server').done(function(){

});
```

Server.js

```
 function cb(){
  // do stuff
 }

 // ajax request is going here
 function Server(req, res) {
   GetTheModelFromTheDbInAsyncWay(function(cb){
      cb();
   });
 }

 function GetTheModelFromTheDbInAsyncWay(cb) {
    //doing stuff to the db e.g getting the result of a query
    // ...
     cb(result);
 }
```

What technique do I need to use, to retrieve the aync server request in my async ajax request?
I think it will be something like `promised`.
But how can I pass it back to my ajax request since, the db request is async by itself

Hope I was able to make this clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're **calling** the argument you receive from `GetTheModelFromTheDbInAsyncWay` as though it were a function. Presumably it isn't. You should be *using* it (for instance, sending it or information derived from it via `res.send`):

```
// ajax request is going here
function Server(req, res) {
  GetTheModelFromTheDbInAsyncWay(function(data){ // Not `cb`, `data`
     // Use `data` here to produce the response you send via `res`
  });
}
```

Comment: oh I feel dump ^^

Comment: @xhallix: We've all been there. :-)